# Rails routing error beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, crud

I'm definitely doing this wrong but I can't figure out the right way to do it... I am a rails newbie and would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

I want to print out all the information about a store when I am getting it from the API.  When I am setting up the models, I have a property in the store object `t.references reviews`.  Now I have the store printing to a JSON at `localhost/api/stores/0` and it has an array of review's indexes `[0]`.  How can I make it so that it is sending all the info back rather than the id... for instance

`store: { name: tester, reviews: { id: 0, text: "test review" } }`

i was thinking something like this, but I think it is wrong:

```
   def show
    store = @store
    review = Review.find(store.review_id) <- will do a for loop but i temporarily made this a single id

    displayStore = Hash.new

    displayStore["store"] = store
    displayStore["reviews"] = review

    render json: displayStore
  end
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly render an object as JSON

```
render :json => @store
```

If you want to render store and review, then you can make another ruby class with store and review as instance variables and render that class instead

i.e if class Example has review and store

```
render :json => @example
```